# nginx - Apache ReWriteRule

Tags: nginx

I'm new to nginx and need to include the following Apache ReWriteRule:

```
RewriteRule ^download_download_([a-z]{2})/(.*)$            /download_download/$2         [QSA,L]
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can **generally** always change Apache's `RerwiteRule abc xyz` to `rewrite abc xyz;` in Nginx.

Apache's `[QSA,L]` is simply `last` in Nginx.

The twist with yours is that you have curly braces `{...}` in your regex. Curly braces have an internal use in Nginx and as a result, you need to wrap the regex string in quotation marks `"..."` for Nginx to correctly parse the regex.

So you can try

`rewrite "^download_download_([a-z]{2})/(.*)$" /download_download/$2 last;`

Comment: Had to add a slash in the beginning. rewrite "^/download_download_([a-z]{2})/(.*)$" /download_download/$2 last; Now ist working fine. Thx!